# wp_get_update_data() function running on every admin request

Tags: wp-admin, updates, performance

In one specific instance of a WordPress build the admin is incredibly slow, after checking the issue out with the Query Monitor plugin I notice that WordPress is running a handfull (~15) HTTP requests whenever you click around the admin panel.

These requests are all fired from the `wp_get_update_data()` function, of which goes away to fetch plugin versions to check if the local plugins are up-to-date.

The issue here is this function is running for every request, and it's a big performance issue.

I've never had this on the hundreds of WordPress instances I've build before, does anyone know what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

If it's native behavior (and not something like third party extensions screwing it up) then update checks should basically fire if there is no data or the time for next check have passed.

My educated guess would be it's one of the two:

- your install not being able to store transients correctly (thus data always empty)
- your install having time screwed up (thus always "behind" the time to check)

But to say with certainty need to pretty much take that logic apart and step through. I did such before, it's pretty murky code spaghetti around there in core.

Comment: many thanks for your reply... I'm just looking into the transients now so will investigate that further.